# Copy subfolders and their content up one level?

Tags: robocopy, xcopy

Right now I have the following structure

```
Folder 1\ 
      -Apr2007\folder 1
              \folder 2
              \folder 3
      -May 2007\folder 23
              \folder 24
              \folder 25
      -June 2007
              \folder 41
              \folder 42
              \folder 43

      -etc all the way to 2018
```

How can I copy the subfolders and their content under the months so they are all in one directory? I tried using the For /f command but I don't know how to specify 2 wildcards in the command. I would need a wildcard for the month and also one for the name of the subfolder since they are all different.

I would like the following output:

```
New folder\
              folder 1\
              folder 2\
              folder 3\
              folder 23\
              folder 24\
              folder 25\
              folder 41\
              folder 42\
              folder 43\
```

Comment: So you are asking to have all `~/<month> <year>` subfolders with names such as `/folder <##>` to all be copied over to a different and specific folder instead?

Comment: Well I want to take the folder under the month year folder and move it elsewhere with all of its content. Or move it up one level if it's easier.

Comment: I was thinking of something similar to what AFH indicated in his answer. Give it a try and see if that will suffice for your needs, I will check back in a little while tho as I have an issue I'm working on now.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need two nested `for` loops:-

```
for /d %d in ("\Full\Path\To\Folder 1"\*) do ( cd "%d" & for /d %s in (*) do xcopy /s "%s"\* "\Full\Path\To\New folder\%s"\ )
```

If you put it in a batch file, you need to double the `%` signs.

Using `cd` is one option, but you can also use full directory paths, though it will need variable parsing to define the target path.

Comment: Can i use a varibale for folder 1? there is about 60 folders and 50 000 subfolders. I would like not having to mention exact folder names in the command.

Comment: Yes, certainly you can, either for the the folder name or the full path. In a batch file it can be a parameter, as can the destination folder. You may want to add checks that the destination folder does not exist already, or if you want to merge into an existing folder, that you do not overwrite existing files.

Comment: That seeems to work. Let say I would need to copy 15 000 specified folders, is there a way to supply a list of folder names to copy and if the folder name matches, it will copy those folders? I know you can use an exclusion list with xcopy but I would need an inclusion list instead of an exclusion list if that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by adding a `findstr` for each subdirectory (`%s`) to check if it's in the directory list, but you are significantly changing your question, and I can't give you more information unless you give a lot more details of what you want, including the format of the directory name list.

Comment: I have a folder list as a text file generated by a software with a folder name on each line without the path to each folder and I would like a command to go through this text file and copy the matching folders to a new location.

Comment: What proportion of the folders will be in the list? This will determine whether it is more efficient to step through the list and look for each folder or find all the folders and check whether each one is in the list.

Comment: The whole folder name will be in the list.

Comment: You can use `for /f "delims=" %d in ('type DirList.txt') do xcopy ...`. You will need to parse `%d` in the `xcopy` command, depending on the list format.

Comment: Could you give me more info on how to parse the variable? like an example of what the whole command look like?

Comment: Type `for /?` to get a list of the parsing options at the end of the help text. Since you haven't given an example of the precise format of the directory list file, I can't give a useful example of the parse string, but you should be able to work it out from the `for /?` information.

Comment: The text file would look like this(one entry per line not all beside each other):

12134
57896
45789
69875
74514
etc..

These numbers are the folder names and there is about 15 000 of them.

Comment: That conflicts with your previous statement: "The whole folder name will be in the list." You know the format, so why can't you work out the answer from the information you now have?

Comment: It's because I don't really understand the command. I run it and see the results but I don't understand it fully to write it on my own. thanks for your help it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I managed to get it working using this command:
FOR /F %F IN (folderlist.txt) DO xcopy /I /E "pathrofoldersource\%F" "pathtocopysource\%F"

Is there a way that I can apply this command but I want to copy only the folder at the lowest level of 2 level hiearchy?
D:\System\Jan2018\Folder1-120000
D:\System\Feb2018\Folder1-120000


So basically I want the command to copy the folders specified in the text file that are listed in the 1-120 000 structure under tthe month folders but I also need to specify a variable for the month folder, so somehting like

Comment: It looks as though you ran out of space in your comment. I have been waiting for you to finish it: it doesn't make sense as it stands, since my answer appears to do what you want, apart from the text file which you have since introduced. Please update your question to explain the format of the text file and how it relates to the live directories.